# asp button on click is fired on local machine but it does not fire on published server

Tags: asp.net, button

I cannot understand why but I have a button inside a panel (attached to an Ajax Modal Popup Extender), This button onclick gets fired on local machinw but it does not work on the uploaded server online.
Do you know what might be causing this behaviour?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUpsertCommodity" runat="server" Width="70" Text="Submit"  OnClick="btnUpsertCommodity_Click"  ValidationGroup="Commodity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try setting CausesValidation property

see this for details
[button CauseValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error once. I'm explaining why -

Check the Page Directive of your `aspx` page. Here, the `CodeFile="Mypage.aspx.cs"` property points to the Codebehind file where the `button_click` event will be written. Sometimes, this codefile property contains a relative URL to the Codebehind file like this : `CodeFile="~/Mypage.aspx.cs"`. This relative URLs does not work after Server Deployment and can't redirect a button click event to the corresponding Event Handler. Thats why, you will see the page, but clicking the button will yield nothing.

Ckeck if you have done the same. If so, just remove the `~/` part from your page directive.